# how to execute a c function which is written in informix?

Tags: informix

I have written a C function which print hello world
and registered as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func()
RETURNING INT
EXTERNAL NAME "/tmp/mytest.c"
LANGUAGE C
END FUNCTION;
```

placed the c code in `/tmp/mytest.c` in Informix server and the above function created. But when I am executing the function in dbeaver I am getting below error.

```
SQL Error[IX000]:User Defined Routine (my_func) module load failed
```

I have a Informix function which should call C function

Comment: You need the function compiled; it should be a shared object.  Also, standard output in the server goes to `/dev/null`, so you won’t see any output. Your function needs to return a value.  And use the appropriate API calls to do so.

Comment: Have a look at chapter 10 (10.2.3 to be specific) from the IBM Informix Developer's Handbook.  https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247884.pdf   It shows how to create a simple C routine and how to call it from SQL